# CSRF verification failed when logging into admin panel

Tags: django

In production my app is giving me `CSRF verification failed` when I log into my admin panel.

I have the following in my settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

As my site doesn't currently have an SSL certificate I have ignored the following after running `python manage.py check --deploy`:

```
?: (security.W004) You have not set a value for the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting. If your entire site is served only over SSL, you may want to consider setting a value and enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security. Be sure to read the documentation first; enabling HSTS carelessly can cause serious, irreversible problems.
?: (security.W008) Your SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting is not set to True. Unless your site should be available over both SSL and non-SSL connections, you may want to either set this setting True or configure a load balancer or reverse-proxy server to redirect all connections to HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use those two settings then you must be using SSL.

See:

[SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#session-cookie-secure)

[CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure)